# How to call the betaQuantile function in matlab

Tags: matlab, mupad

I am trying to call the betaQuantile function from Mupad in a m-file so I can run it in Matlab2014b.
I was look at these two help files which seem to be relevant but still cannot figure out the code
http://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-betaquantile.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

http://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your question to show the code you're using so we can provide specific help. Do you really need the symbolic math version of this? Why not use the numeric [`betainv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/betainv.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realized that the question is not so relevant anymore, should I delete this question?

Comment: You can always delete your own question, however, if you've solved your problem and think your solution might benefit others, you're also welcome to answer and even accept your own question.